# does rejson in redis support complex get query?

Tags: json, redis, redisjson

I am going through `rejson` docs [jsonget](http://rejson.io/commands/#jsonget) and cannot find anything related to complex query as for example:

`JSON.GET key1 where key1.subkey1 == "test1 || key3.subkey6.subsubkey2 > 2"`

Does anybody know if `redis` supports such a logic with `json` output? If not, what are the alternatives ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - ReJSON does not support complex query logic. What you could do is couple it (in the application) with RediSearch (https://redisearch.io) to index and search your documents.

Disclaimer: ReJSON author here and involved in RediSearch's development to a degree :)

Comment: How would you recommend coupling ReJSON and RediSearch together? I am still new to Redis, but it looks like RediSearch is used to query an index of strings.  

Let's say I had an array of JSON objects with an integer and a string put into Redis using ReJSON.

My goal is to retrieve an integer from one of those JSON objects based on a query of their strings.

If I created a RedisSearch index of those strings and performed a query, how would I then retrieve the integer I want from the JSON object inside of Redis using ReJSON?

Comment: Good question :) @Not_a_golfer and I had discussed it in length... two ways to go about it a) do it with client/application-side glue b) extend RediSearch to support arbitrary get/set commands (as it currently does only w/ hashes). Option a - you can implement it, option b - could come as a feature someday.

Comment: If I understand RediSearch correctly, you can create an index that is ('text to search', 'id'). And when I conduct a query of 'text', it will return an array of 'id' strings that match. Would it be fine to make these 'id' strings indexes for my JSON data? That way I could use the returned 'id' to make a ReJSON request for data using a command like `JSON.GET myArray [0]` where `0` was a returned 'id' from my RediSearch query.

Comment: @Tylo jup, exactly so.

Comment: @ItamarHaber - Have you considered using jq to add support for complex queries to reJSON? It should not be too difficult...